# Excel Model using a shared drive

Tags: excel

I have an EXCEL worksheet on a shared drive (one drive) and want multiple users to use the model at one time like google sheets.

Does anyone know if a EXCEL for Microsoft 365 file can be opened by multiple users at one time?

Comment: you can.. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/co-author-a-workbook-66ad7ca3-3818-46ac-be5b-6c8dbea8a93e